# Update SASS in Netbeans JRuby?

Tags: ruby, netbeans, sass, jruby

I am using the SCSS-Editor for Netbeans on Windows so that I can edit and compile SCSS files in my projects. SCSS-Editor uses a bundled install of SASS/JRuby, although there is an option to use an external one (I'd prefer not to install the whole Ruby environment just for compiling SCSS files so the bundled one seemed ideal).

For the most part this works fine and I am enjoying using SCSS in my latest project. However, it seems some features of the language (i.e. the %class-name extends) may be unavailable to me due to the bundled SASS being an old version (3.1.20).

I've had a go in the command line (running as admin), but it isn't responding (cursor just there like it expects more). How can I go about updating the bundled SASS install that Netbean's JRuby is using?

Or is there an alternative solution (apart from installing Ruby or using ScoutApp)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this, but I should add as a disclaimer that I haven't conducted any thorough testing. That said, what I've done seems to work okay.

The "External Runtime" setting is just for the SASS runtime; the embedded JRuby version is still used so there's no messing around with Ruby installation. If you go to the [SASS code archive](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=9702) on RubyForge and download and extract the latest tar version (stable is currently 3.2.9) to some appropriate folder, that folder is then suitable for the Sass plugin's "External Sass runtime" location.

The setting (I know you're aware of this, but just to make the answer complete) is in `Tools->Options->Misc->Scss` and put the folder you created into the `SASS/HAML home` box which appears when you select `External Sass Runtime`.

Obviously, there is potential for problems with new SASS on old JRuby and even new SASS on old SCSS-Editor, but my projects seem to compile okay.